# ¿Cómo llamar desde código C un archivo de geogebra?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo un código en C que calcula velocidades, tiempos. Mi duda es, ¿puedo llamar un archivo de geogebra desde C (con código)? Básicamente que se ejecute el archivo de geogebra o, si puedo llamar a la aplicación, que se ejecute. Uso Ubuntu o Windows. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación de GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/manual/en/Reference:Command_Line_Arguments), se puede lanzar el progama directamente desde la línea de comandos abriendo un fichero en particular. Lo que tienes que hacer sería algo como esto (traducción mía):

- Si usas los ficheros *.jar directamente:

  ```
  java -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -jar geogebra.jar [OPCIONES] [FICHEROS]
  ```
- En Windows (si se instaló con el instalador off-line):

  ```
  geogebra.exe [OPCIONES] [FICHEROS]
  ```
- En Linux (si se instaló con paquetes deb o rpm):

  ```
  geogebra [OPCIONES] [FICHEROS]
  ```

Eso abrirá GeoGebra con las OPCIONES especificadas (puedes ver la lista en el enlace de arriba) y abre los FICHEROS indicados.

Ahora lo que hace falta es poder realizar la llamada para ejecutar esos comandos desde C/C++. Para ello puedes utilizar [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) combinándolo con lo explicado en la lista de arriba. Por ejemplo, si estás en Windows, harías algo como:

```
system("geogebra.exe nombre_fichero_a_abrir.ggb");
```

Suponiendo que el directorio de GeoGebra esté en el path, si no, tendrás que poner la ruta completa al ejecutable.

Comment: acertada tu respuesta, se resolvió mi problema; en mi caso estoy usando Ubuntu para correr mi código, sólo usé system("geogebra tiro.ggb"); y se ejecuta bien, gracias